# SSL fails on Wordpress mobile (denied Google listing)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, mobile

I have an issue: on mobile chrome shows a "!" icon before the url (which means ssl error); but on web all ssl tests pass.

There is a significant downside: [www.bolinas.berlin](http://www.bolinas.berlin) is not listed on Google Search and we can not get the site "registered" with our Google Maps entry.

The site runs on Wordpress 6.4.2 running Divi theme & hosted by our ISP Strato.de

I would be really really thankful for any pointers.

Best
Max

I looked into the WP setup and it says its 100% healthy; but on the Strato (ISP) dashboard there is a "!" next to the WP link too

Comment: Its working fine on mobile chrome browser.

Comment: Ensure that your SSL certificate is compatible with mobile browsers. Some older or less common types of SSL certificates might not be recognized by all mobile browsers. you can test SSL certificates here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/